# Matrix ODE using Odeintw Python

Tags: python, matrix, ode

The [odeintw](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw) example we get something like this:

```
def asys(a, t, c):
return c.dot(a)

c = np.array([[-0.5, -1.25],
              [ 0.5, -0.25]])
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 201)

# a0 is the initial condition.
a0 = np.array([[0.0, 2.0],
               [2.0, 3.0]])

# Call `odeintw`.
sol = odeintw(asys, a0, t, args=(c,))
```

But I wanna know if it is possible to solve a problem for a  `c` that is time dependent. For it written like (example):

```
c = np.random.rand(201,2,2)
```

I would like to write a function that odeintw understand for each `t` one correspondent `c`. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The principal point to notice is that the ODE solver will evaluate the function `asys` at arbitrary values of `t`. Thus you will need to interpolate the function table for `c`. You would have to check if the existing interpolation functions can handle multi-dimensional arrays. Probably you will need a work-around or wrapper just like `odeintw` provides for `odeint`.

This will work very poorly, if at all, for the presented test example. A random array will give a very jumpy function table, while the ODE solver rely on the differential equation being smooth. Non-smooth behavior leads to very small step sizes and thus very many function evaluations.

Comment: The random array was just an way to exemplify